# VUE -axios GET does not execute

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, axios

My vue porject use axios to send HTTP request.

There is no problem running on Android.

When running on IOS, occasionally the HTTP request is not sent.

But not every IOS mobile phone will have this situation, this kind of problem can only be solved by uninstalling and reinstalling the APP.

```
getInfo() {
  let params = { device_id: this.info_id.device_id };
  axios.get(device_detail, params, this.headers).then(res => {
    if (!res.code) {
      this.product_id = res.data.device_type;
      this.home_id = res.data.home_id;
      localStorage.setItem("product_id", this.product_id);
      localStorage.setItem("home_id", this.home_id);
      localStorage.setItem("product_num_id", res.data.product_id);
      localStorage.setItem("classify_id", res.data.classify_id);
      this.getFuncList();
    }
  });
},


get(url, param, headers) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url,
        params: param,
        headers: headers
      }).then(res => {
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
  },
this.headers = {
  token: this.token,
  appid: this.appid,
  lang:  this.$i18n.locale,
};
```

getInfo() run in created()

I use localStorage.setItem() to save data like "token"  "appid".

I found that axios does not executed, I don`t know why,but if you uninstalling and reinstalling the APP,problem solved.

why????

excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've last used vue.js but as far as I remember you need to define getInfo() function as *async* since it calls a function which returns a promise. Other than that, by using *await*, waiting for result of the *get* function could solve your problem. I might be completely wrong though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async`/`await` instead -- your code will be more legible and consistent with Vue's approach to aysnchronous methods. Also wrap your `await`s in a `try`/`catch` block. That way, you'll be able to see exactly what the error is when it fails and therefore why it's failing.

```js
async getInfo() {
  try {
    let params = { device_id: this.info_id.device_id };
    const res = await axios.get(device_detail, params, this.headers);
    if (!res.code) {
      this.product_id = res.data.device_type;
      this.home_id = res.data.home_id;
      localStorage.setItem("product_id", this.product_id);
      localStorage.setItem("home_id", this.home_id);
      localStorage.setItem("product_num_id", res.data.product_id);
      localStorage.setItem("classify_id", res.data.classify_id);
      this.getFuncList();
    };
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
},


async get(url, param, headers) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url,
      params: param,
      headers: headers
    });
    return res;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,I use your code to catch error,the first time,I catch error in `getInfo()`,it prints a **type error:undefined is not a object**,and then, I tried to catch error in `get()`,suddenly it was found that the problem had been solved!!  but I still dont know why.I updated the code twice,the first time I use your code,problem still,and the second time I just add `this.test = err` under `console.error(err)`,and the problem solved,crazy.